# What is BCS weak coupling Pauli limit?

Tags: superconductivity

What is BCS weak coupling Pauli limit Hp? How Hp=1.84Tc relation is derived? 
Please suggest suitable reference regarding that.

Comment: It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking. Please add further information about the context so that potential answerers will know exactly what the issue here is.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that the question was quite unclear, but I think I have understood what you are asking for. You want to know how to derive the critical paramagnetic field for a weak-coupling superconductor at zero temperature $T=0$. This quantity is derived by equating the magnetization polarization energy with the condensation energy of the superconducting state, namely $$\frac{1}{2}\chi_{\rm n}H_{\rm p}^2=\frac{1}{2}N_0\Delta_0^2.$$ Above, $\Delta_0=1.764k_{\rm B}T_{\rm C}$ is the superconducting order parameter in the weak coupling limit ($k_{\rm B}$ is the Boltzmann constant) and $\chi_{\rm n}=g^2\mu_{\rm B}^2N_0/2$ is the magnetic susceptibility in the normal state ($\mu_{\rm B}$ is the Bohr magneton, $N_0$ is the densisty of state at the Fermi level and $g\simeq2$ for a free electron). If you insert above the physical constants and you solve for the magnetic field, you find $$H_{\rm p}[T]\sim1.85 T_{\rm C}[K] $$ where the magnetic field is expressed in Tesla and the critical temperature is expressed in Kelvin. As a reference, I suggest to you the old but excellent review by Fulde: Peter Fulde (1973): High field superconductivity in thin films, Advances in Physics, 22:6, 667-719 (https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00018737300101369).